# Number of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{60}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Find the number of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{60}.$

*Attempt.* The $12$ sets of the form $$<[2^a3^b5^c]_{60}>=\{[2^a3^b5^c]_{60}[d]_{60}:~[d]_{60}\in \mathbb{Z}_{60}\},$$ for $a=0,1,2$ and $b,c=0,1$ 
are ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ (can be proved). Are they the only ones though?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those are all of them. Note that an ideal of your ring is necessarily a subgroup of the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}/60\mathbb{Z}$. But this group is cyclic, so there is exactly one subgroup for each divisor $d|60$. How many divisors of $60$ are they?

Comment: Very good answer, by means of group theory, i got it! By the way, are you aware of an approach by means of ring theory only?